# Does it exist a complete chain tool that allows to manage requirements (e.g. ProR), realize UML diagrams, develop code and perform test?

Tags: uml, traceability, requirements-management

I would like to know if exist a complete tool chain to:
- manage requirements (e.g. ProR)
- realize UML diagrams (use case, activity, class and sequence)
- develop code
- perform test (e.g. junit)
Last but not least, is it possible to mantain traceability among all these parts?

Francesco

Answer (score 0):

IBM Rational offers products from requirements management through modeling and code generation.  See their DOORS and RequisitePro for requirements management.  See Rhapsody for modeling and code generation.  DOORS and ReqPro offer traceability automation.